# Presto unnest/map complex json

Tags: sql, presto, unnest

I've been on stack for a few hours exploring examples of other presto unnest/map/cast solutions but I can't seem to find one that works for my data.

Here's a sample of my data:

```
with test_data (id, messy_json) AS (
    VALUES ('TEST_A', JSON '{"issue":[],"problem":[{"category":"math","id":2,"name":"subtraction"},{"category":"math","id":3,"name":"division"},{"category":"english","id":25,"name":"verbs"},{"category":"english","id":27,"name":"grammar"},{"category":"language","id":1,"name":"grammar"}],"version":4}'),
           ('TEST_B', JSON '{"problem":[],"version":4}'),
           ('TEST_C', JSON '{"version": 4, "problem": [], "issue": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}')
),
```

The JSON column is semi-unstructured and can hold multiple lvls / doesn't always have every key:value pair as other rows.

I was trying solutions like:

```
with test_data AS (
select id,
       messy_json        
from larger_tbl),


select 
    id as id,
    json_extract_scalar(test_data, '$.version') as lvl1_version
    json_extract_scalar(lvl2, '$.problem') as lvl2_id
    from test
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(messy_json) AS array(json))) AS x(lvl1) ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_extract(lvl1, '$.problem') AS array(json))) AS y(lvl2) ON TRUE
```

This gets me cast errors etc. I've tried some variations with

```
unnest(cast(json_col as map(varchar, map(varchar,varchar)) options too.
```

My goal is to explode the entire dataset with the retained ID and all keys/multi-lvl keys retained in a long dataset. I appreciate any input/guidance, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest your current query does not make much sense based on provided sample data and stated goals.

- `UNNEST` is used with `cross join` rather then `left join` (I use succinct syntax skipping the keyword completely)
- No need to `json_parse(messy_json)` in your test data since it is already json (though I assume in the real data it just a varchar field then it should be kept)
- Root json is a json object, so it can't be casted to array (and there is no need to).
- `problem` in `json_extract_scalar(lvl2, '$.problem') as lvl2_id` should be changed to `id` since `problem` array was already unnested
- To handle cases where the problem array is empty you can use approach with [unnesting multiple arrays](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) with a dummy one with 1 element

```sql
-- sample data
with test_data (id, messy_json) AS (
    VALUES ('TEST_A', JSON '{"issue":[],"problem":[{"category":"math","id":2,"name":"subtraction"},{"category":"math","id":3,"name":"division"},{"category":"english","id":25,"name":"verbs"},{"category":"english","id":27,"name":"grammar"},{"category":"language","id":1,"name":"grammar"}],"version":4}'),
           ('TEST_B', JSON '{"problem":[],"version":4}'),
           ('TEST_C', JSON '{"version": 4, "problem": [], "issue": [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}')
)

-- query
select id
     , json_extract_scalar(messy_json, '$.version') as lvl1_version
     , json_extract_scalar(lvl2, '$.id')            as lvl2_id
from test_data
   , UNNEST(CAST(json_extract(messy_json, '$.problem') 
       AS array(json)), array[1]) AS y(lvl2, ignored);
```

Output:

| id | lvl1_version | lvl2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST_A | 4 | 2 |
| TEST_A | 4 | 3 |
| TEST_A | 4 | 25 |
| TEST_A | 4 | 27 |
| TEST_A | 4 | 1 |
| TEST_B | 4 | NULL |
| TEST_C | 4 | NULL |

Comment: thanks a ton! Your answer helped me get to where I need. Much appreciated!

Comment: @DerrickTsoi was glad to help. If answer either for you - please mark it as accepted one.