# separate nested columns into rows [sql]

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I was trying with  cross join  and  unnest , but I only managed to split one column, not all three at the same time

I have this table in amazon athena
[image]

and I want to separate the columns with lists into rows, leaving a table like this

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 765045 | 5782 | jd938 | 1 | a | pickup |
| 765045 | 5782 | jd938 | 2 | b | delivery |
| 41118 | 78995 | kd982 | 5 | g | pickup |
| 41118 | 78995 | kd982 | 8 | q | delivery |
| 411620 | 65852 | km0899 | 9 | k | pickup |
| 411620 | 65852 | km0899 | 6 | b | delivery |

```
select 
     t.COL1, t.COL2,t.COL3, u.COL4
from t
cross join
     unnest(t.COL4) u(COL4)
```

I was thinking of making subtables and repeating this code 3 times but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way

Comment: Just FYI it seems that `8` should be `k`, not `q` in the expected table.

Answer (score 2):

[`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) supports handling multiple columns in one statement. Also you can use succinct syntax omitting the `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
select 
     t.COL1, t.COL2,t.COL3, u.COL4, u.COL5, u.COL6
from t,
     unnest(t.COL4, t.COL5, t.COL6) AS u(COL4, COL5, COL6)
```

Note that for array of different cardinality it will substitute missing values with `null`'s. And if all arrays are empty the row will not be added to the final result (but you can work around this by adding a dummy array with one element like was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550074/2501279)).